# How to call a helper function within a Promise'd function

Tags: javascript, promise, helper

I am still new to Javascript and I'm hoping someone out there can help me with a problem I'm having that I just haven't been able to wrap my head around!!

I have a function with a lot of duplicate code in it, so tried to spin it off into a helper function. However when I call the helper function from within the lMS function (which is currently being called as `lMS(f).then(`), the helper function executes AFTER the `init(g)` function which is reliant on lMS executing and completing first.

I'm 99% sure that I'm having this issue due to my misunderstanding of how `Promise`s work and the nature of async functions.

I have tried pushing the duplicate code into a separate function and calling that when it is needed. I have tried capturing the responses of that as Promises, or pushing the responses into an array and then only executing when I have all items returned (compared to the original array).

The following is the *original* script, where there is no helper function but a good chunk of duplicate code: https://github.com/willstocks-tech/dynamically-polyfill-features-for-a-script/releases/tag/0.0.5b5 - line 57 (`function loadMyScript(url)`)

I have put the helper code into a Codepen (I've been working on it for a few days) https://codepen.io/willstocks_tech/pen/pGgRrG?editors=1012

### Update

Included `init` function within "helper function" code and a new pen to detail everything I have tried/am currently trying based on feedback:
https://codepen.io/willstocks_tech/pen/YBEzLW?editors=1012

Current code:

```
function lMS(f) {
    if(Array.isArray(f)) {
        var urlen = f.length;
        for (var u = 0; u < urlen; u++) {
            var uri = f[u];
            if(uri !== null && uri !== '') {
                return new Promise(
                    function(resolve, reject) {
                        var thescript = document.createElement('script');
                        thescript.src = encodeURI(uri);
                        document.body.appendChild(thescript);
                        thescript.onerror = function(response) {
                            return reject("Loading the script failed!", response);
                        } 
                        thescript.onload = function() {
                            return resolve("Script setup and ready to load!");
                        } 
                    }
                )
            } else {
                return new Promise( //pretty sure this could just be Promise.resolve();
                    function(resolve, reject) {
                        return resolve ("No script to load");
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    } else {
        if(f !== null && f !== '') {
            return new Promise(
                function(resolve, reject) {
                    var thescript = document.createElement('script');
                    thescript.src = encodeURI(f);
                    document.body.appendChild(thescript);
                    thescript.onerror = function(response) {
                        return reject("Loading the script failed!", response);
                    } 
                    thescript.onload = function() {
                        return resolve("Script setup and ready to load!");
                    } 
                }
            )
        } else {
            return new Promise( //pretty sure this could just be Promise.resolve();
                function(resolve, reject) {
                    return resolve ("No script to load");
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

New work in progress (with helper):

```
function pL(e, f, g) {
    cNS(e).then(
        function() {
            lMS(f, g)
        }
    ).catch(function(error){return error})
    }
}

function lMS(f, g) {
    var w = [];
    if(Array.isArray(f)) {
        var urlen = f.length;
        for (var u = 0; u < urlen; u++) {
            var uri = f[u];
            if(uri !== null && uri !== '') {
                uriProm(uri); //go and get a script that is needed
                w.push(uri);  //maybe push to array and return resolve once everything is done?
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
        if(w.length === url.length && w.every(function(value, index) { return value === url[index]})) {
            console.log("We've made it to here");
            return init(g) //go off to run a piece of code based reliant on the script of uriProm
            }
    } else { //not an array of values
        if(url !== null && url !== '') {
            uriProm(uri);
            return init(g)
        } else {
            return
        }
    }
}

//helper function (avoiding duplicate code)
function uriProm(uri){
    var thescript = document.createElement('script');
    thescript.src = encodeURI(uri);
    document.body.appendChild(thescript);
    thescript.onerror = function(response) {
        return reject("Loading the script failed!", response);
    } 
    thescript.onload = function() {
        return Promise.resolve();
    } 
}

    function init(g) {
        if(Array.isArray(g)) {
            var fnlen = g.length;
            for (var f = 0; f < fnlen; f++) {
                try {
                    new Function(g[f])();
                } catch(err) {
                    console.error('There was an error: ', err.name, err.stack);
                }
            }           
        } else {    
            try {
                new Function(g)();
            } catch(err) {
                console.error('There was an error: ', err.name, err.stack);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "*pretty sure this could just be Promise.resolve();*" - yes indeed

Comment: In your current code, you `return` the promises from within the loop, instead of pushing them to some `w` array? Keep the same functionality please

Comment: What are `init` and `pL`, where did they come from?

Comment: In your helper function `uriProm`, you are forgetting the `new Promise` line. No, you cannot just place a `Promise.resolve()` in an asynchronous callback.

Comment: @Bergi - thanks for the prompt responses! So I have gone through various iterations, including your suggestion of retaining promising uriProm, however the same issue persists - for some reason the `uriProm` function executes AFTER the `init` function, which ultimately results in failure.

Comment: For example @Bergi: 
`function uriProm(uri) { return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) { var thescript = document.createElement('script'); thescript.src = encodeURI(uri); document.body.appendChild(thescript); thescript.onerror = function(response) { return reject("Loading the script failed!", response); } thescript.onload = function() { return resolve("Script setup and ready to load!"); } } ) }`

Comment: A better explanation of what I'm trying to achieve is [here](https://github.com/willstocks-tech/dynamically-polyfill-features-for-a-script/blob/develop/dynamicpolyfill.js)

Comment: @Bergi - I also tried the following: [https://codepen.io/willstocks_tech/pen/YBEzLW?editors=1012](https://codepen.io/willstocks_tech/pen/YBEzLW?editors=1012) but with no luck :(

Comment: Yes, that's what `uriProm` should look like. Make it so.

Comment: Then use `uriProm(uri).then(init)` if you want the `init` call to wait for the promise to be fulfilled. But really it's unclear what `init` is, since it doesn't occur in the current code.

Comment: I will give that another go @Bergi - maybe I just had it formatted strangely! RE: Init: `function initialiseMyScript(functionToRunonLoad){if(Array.isArray(functionToRunonLoad)){var fnlen=functionToRunonLoad.length;for(var f=0;f<fnlen;f++){try{new Function(functionToRunonLoad[f])()}catch(err){console.error("There was an error: ",err.name,err.stack)}}}else{try{console.log(functionToRunonLoad);new Function(functionToRunonLoad)()}catch(err){console.error("There was an error: ",err.name,err.stack)}}}` - I will edit the original!

Comment: @Bergi - I have been playing with this some more overnight and I _think_ I'm getting somewhere. Per your suggestion, I have implemented `uriProm(uri).then(function(){init(g)});`, however obviously it goes through each of the array values individually. If a user were to not order the array to pass to `lMS()` and `init()` in the correct order, the script would fail to initialise still. Is this where `Promise.all` would come into play outside of the `for` and then `.then` on that `Promise.all` or am I misunderstanding? Example: https://codepen.io/willstocks_tech/pen/YBEzLW?editors=1012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of trying and tonnes of research, I worked out how I can do this.

Using `Array.forEach` to iterate through the array values (rather than trying to `for` loop) means I can push each promise to an array and then `Promise.all` on the array! :)

```js
//This won't run in JSFiddle because the rest of the function doesn't exist
//https://github.com/willstocks-tech/dynamically-polyfill-features-for-a-script/releases - 0.0.5-beta.6

function lMS(f, g) {
  if (Array.isArray(f)) { //Check whether array is being passed or just string
    var promises = []; //Gotta catch 'em all... as an array
    f.forEach( //iterate through the array using Array.forEach()
      function(f) { //pass each item in the array through to the "get script" function
        promises.push(nbU(f)) //push the resolve/reject into the promises array
      }
    );
    Promise.all(promises) //Make sure that all promises that are returned come back as resolved
      .then( //then
        () => init(g) //run the init function!
      );
  } else if (!Array.isArray(f) && f !== null && f !== '') { //if not an array and not blank values
    return nonblankURL(f) //resolve or reject getting the script
      .then( //then
        () => init(g) //run the init function!
      )
  } else { //not array, blank values
    return init(g); //straight to init because no dependency (blank)
  }
}
```

I can confirm that this is working as expected now! https://codepen.io/willstocks_tech/pen/YBEzLW?editors=1012

I've grown to understand Promises/asynchronous code execution a bit more :) Thanks @Bergin for all of the assistance